# Access derived class property that is visible during runtime

Tags: c#

I wasn't sure how to title this question so maybe the description will help.

I am new to coding and want to use Inheritance to minimize my code.

I have two base class and two derived classes I am using:
Base Class 1:

```
public class TDXInput
{
    public SCContext SCContext { get; set; }
    public ToolContext ToolContext { get; set; }
    public WaferContainer WaferContainer { get; set; }
}
```

Derived Class 1:

```
public class CURTDXInput : TDXInput
{

}
```

Base Class 2:

```
public class WaferContainer
{
    public WaferContext WaferContext = new WaferContext();
    public List<WaferImage> ImageList = new List<WaferImage>();
    public List<WaferDieResults> WaferResultList = new List<WaferDieResults>();
    public List<WaferDieMeasurements> WaferMeasurementList = new List<WaferDieMeasurements>();
    public List<DieData> DieDataList = new List<DieData>();
}
```

Derived Class 2:

```
public class CURWaferContainer : WaferContainer
{
    //public CURWaferContext WaferContext = new CURWaferContext();
    public List<CURWaferImage> CURImageList = new List<CURWaferImage>();
    public List<CURWaferDieResults> CURWaferResultList = new List<CURWaferDieResults>();
    public List<CURWaferDieMeasurements> CURWaferMeasurementList = new List<CURWaferDieMeasurements>();
    public List<CURDieData> CurDieDataList = new List<CURDieData>();

}
```

The idea is that there is an umbrella format called TDXinput that has 3 main sections, SCCOntext, ToolCOntext,  and WaferContainer.

However there are tools that have their own uniqueness for these 3 section but also have a few similarities. Because of this I started to use inheritance.

A big goal is to be able to pass in an input like CURTDXInput to a general function that takes in the base class TDXInput so I don't have to rewrite that function each time a new TDXInput tool comes in:

```
public static TDX2KlarfResult CheckTDXInput(TDXInput input, TDX2KlarfResult result)
{
    if (input.ToolContext == null)
    {
        result.success = false;
        return result;

    }

    if (input.WaferContainer == null)
    {

        Logger.Warn("Missing Wafer Container Skipping the file");
        result.success = false;
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

For the implementation above it does work but then I run into issues I am forced to use the base class instead of the derived class like so:

```
List<CURDieData> dieDataList = input.WaferContainer.DieDataList.OfType<CURDieData>().ToList();
```

When I inspect input during debugging in Visual studio I can see the value for CurDieDataList (which I want) from the CURWaferContainer class but I only can reference DieDataList from the WaferContainer class  which I then have to cast to CURDieData List. Is there a way for me to access CurDieDataList?

Also am I using inheritance correctly or is there a way I can get around not having to overload CheckTDXInput(TDXInput input, TDX2KlarfResult result) for each TDXInput derived type.

Comment: Re. your side question: [Inheritance is not a mechanism for code reuse.](https://www.arhohuttunen.com/misconceptions-about-code-reuse/) IMO, inheritance is one of the last concepts that new coders should be introduced to. The only topic that causes more confusion and brain damage is threads.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Is there any way to write a function that can handle different classes/types that have similar properties like I am trying to do with that CheckTDXInput function?

Answer (score 0):

in that function you have a TDXInput. That gives you a WeferContainer.Fine but it not guaranteed what type that WaferContainer is

The simple thing to do is

```
 if(input.WaferContainer is CURWaferContainer){
    var cwc = input.WaferContainer as CURWaferContainer;
    // you now have the CURWaferContainer instance and can get at its data
```

Is this optimal?. Its hard to say, your object model is pretty complex. Testing objects for their type is a classic 'code smell'. A common solution would be for WaferContainer to have a virtual method called, say, GetMainDieList.

Its hard to say whats best tho

Comment: I am not familiar with the "as" clause in C#. I think I will roll back the inheritance model. What this means now is I'd have to rewrite that function each time for each derived class of TDXInput. Is there a way to make a generic function that can handle different classes with similar fields?

Comment: @Datboydozy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator

Comment: Ok I see. The only issue with your logic there is that it always will be WaferContainer since it's only seeing the local TDXInput before runtime and during runtime, it still only searches for TDXinput's member properties which CURWaferContainer is not a part of @pm100